# order database using two columns or more

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a database of users 
every user have a first name , last name and age
I want to order my data base using last name, than if two user have the same last name i want to organize the data base using first name and finally age

What do i need to add to this line?

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(DATABASE_ATTENDEES_TABLE, null, Attendee.DATABASE_KEY_USER_ID + " = ?", new String[] { Long.toString(user_id) }, null, null, Attendee.DATABASE_KEY_LASTNAME);
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks i get it:

```
Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(
    DATABASE_ATTENDEES_TABLE, 
    null, 
    Attendee.DATABASE_KEY_USER_ID + " = ?", 
    new String[] { Long.toString(userId) }, 
    null, 
    null, 
    Attendee.DATABASE_KEY_LASTNAME+ " ASC," + 
        Attendee.DATABASE_KEY_FIRSTNAME  + " ASC," +
        Attendee.DATABASE_KEY_AGE
);
```